# React setState when element in a child updates

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am relatively new to Javascript and React and am trying to get a page together to record holiday dates.  I have it running with react-day-picker displaying a calendar to pick dates from and then conditionally displaying a child component once I have the date range with the following:

```
{from &&
  to && (
    <DaysSelected range={{ from, to }} setDays={this.holidayDays} />
  )}
```

My child component takes the from and to dates, works out how many days the range covers, and displays the relevant text.

This is great.  But what I would like it to do, and cannot get it to do, is to pass back that number of days to the parent component once it has worked it out.

Well, I can, but I have to do it via an onClick attached to a button as below:

```
render() {
  const { from, to } = this.props.range;
  const numDays = this.weekDaysOnly(from, to);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Your selected holiday dates covers from: {format(from, "DD/MM/YYYY")}{" "}
        to {format(to, "DD/MM/YYYY")}.
      </p>
      <p>this is {numDays} days in length.</p>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => this.props.setDays(numDays)}>
        Confirm Dates
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I'd like it to do is pass it back as soon as it has worked it out but every way I've tried to get it to do that has resulted in errors due to an infinite loop condition (I'm assuming because the setState triggers a re-render, which then triggers my code to work out the days again, which triggers the setState and on and on...)

I'm sure my newbie-ness is preventing me from seeing the obvious solution and would appreciate anyone who could point me in the right direction?

Comment: "But what I would like it to do, and cannot get it to do, is to pass back that number of days to the parent component once it has worked it out". You most likely want to calculate `numDays` in the parent component instead and pass it down as props.

Comment: What is `DaysSelected`? It seems not part of react-day-picker

Comment: @LucaFabbri - DaysSelected is my child component that works out the days and displays the results.  It contains the second code block above.

Comment: @Tholle - All of the code to work out the number of days is in the child component so to move it to the parent would mean eliminating the child entirely and I was trying to stick to the principals of componentisation and keeping my main parent simple - so it just displays or not the child if there is a start and end of range of dates and then the child does the grunt work and displays the results.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, keeping things encapsulated is great, but trying to pass data from the child component to the parent goes against the top-down data flow of React.

Comment: @Tholle but it's a standard pattern that is documented on the React site itself and can be happily implemented using the callback pattern I've implemented with the onClick call attached to my button so I'm not trying to do something weird or unsupported, I'd just like to know how I could fire that callback without having to click a button.